# jest mock constants from gobal module

Tags: mocking, jestjs, expo

I'm playing with Jest and struggling to figure out how to mock an object. Most of the examples I see show how to mock a function.

This is my component `AboutScreen.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Constants, WebBrowser } from 'expo';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import config from '../config';

const AboutScreen = () => {
const { termsAndConditionsUrl, privacyPolicyUrl } = config;
const { releaseChannel, version } = Constants.manifest;
const channel = (releaseChannel === undefined) ? 'DEV' : releaseChannel;
return (
    <View>
        <Text>Version: {version}, Release-channel: {channel}</Text>
        <Text testId={"t-and-c"} onPress={() => WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(termsAndConditionsUrl)}>
    Terms & conditions
        </Text>
    </View>
  );
};


export default AboutScreen;
```

My test in `AboutScreen.test.js` looks like below

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
 import config from '../../config';
 import AboutScreen from '../AboutScreen';
 import { Constants, WebBrowser } from 'expo';
 const { termsAndConditionsUrl, privacyPolicyUrl } = config;

  jest.mock('expo', () => ({
   Constants:{
     manifest: {
       version: '0.0.1',
       releaseChannel: 'PROD',
    }},
  }));

  it('renders with releaseChannel and version', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<AboutScreen />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(wrapper).toContain('PROD');
    expect(wrapper).toContain('0.0.1');
  });

  jest.mock('expo', () => ({
   Constants:{
     manifest: {
       version: '0.0.2',
    }},
  }));

  it('renders with default releaseChannel', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<AboutScreen />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(wrapper).toContain('DEV');
    expect(wrapper).toContain('0.0.2');
   });
```

For the first test, the wrapper should contain 'PROD' and version as '0.0.1'.

But for the second test, the wrapper should contain default value 'DEV'.

The second test seems to keep failing as the mock doesnt override.

I tried other options like

```
jest.mock('expo');
import * as expo from 'expo';
expo.mockReturnValueOnce(); //but fails here as expo has no mockReturnValueOnce
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a handy tip from [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values):

> Note that while you can’t change the values of imports, you can change the objects that they are referring to.

So if you've imported something, you can't just assign it to something else...but if it refers to an *object* then *you can change the object*.

---

In this test `jest.mock` will mock `expo`, and `import { Constants } from 'expo';` will give you access to the mocked `Constants` object...

...and then *you can change that object*:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import config from '../../config';
import AboutScreen from '../AboutScreen';
import { Constants, WebBrowser } from 'expo';
const { termsAndConditionsUrl, privacyPolicyUrl } = config;

jest.mock('expo', () => ({
  Constants: {
    manifest: {
      version: '0.0.1',
      releaseChannel: 'PROD',
    }
  },
}));

it('renders with releaseChannel and version', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<AboutScreen />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();  // Success!
  expect(wrapper.contains('PROD')).toBe(true);  // Success!
  expect(wrapper.contains('0.0.1')).toBe(true);  // Success!
});

it('renders with default releaseChannel', () => {
  Constants.manifest = {
    version: '0.0.2'
  };  // change the manifest property of Constants
  const wrapper = shallow(<AboutScreen />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();  // Success!
  expect(wrapper.contains('DEV')).toBe(true);  // Success!
  expect(wrapper.contains('0.0.2')).toBe(true);  // Success!
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about the imports. That made it clear.

Comment: on similar note, how do I mock `WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync` function. I tried
jest.mock('expo', () => ({
 Constants: {
  manifest: {
   version: '0.0.1',
   releaseChannel: 'PROD',
  },
    WebBrowser: {
      openBrowserAsync: jest.fn()
    }
 },
}));

Comment: @Mateen-Hussain that's a different issue so create a question for it and I'll take a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267277/jest-mock-and-spy-on-an-imported-async-function