# Jest mock and spy on an imported async function

Tags: react-native, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to figure out how to mock an imported properties function in Jest

This is my component `AboutScreen.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Constants, WebBrowser } from 'expo';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const AboutScreen = () => { 
return (
  <View>
    <Text testId={"t-and-c"} onPress={() => WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('tcUrl')}>
Terms & conditions
    </Text>
  </View>
  );
};


export default AboutScreen;
```

My test in AboutScreen.test.js looks like below

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import config from '../../config';
import AboutScreen from '../AboutScreen';
import { Constants, WebBrowser } from 'expo';
const { termsAndConditionsUrl, privacyPolicyUrl } = config;

jest.mock('expo', () => ({
  Constants: {
    manifest: {
        version: '0.0.1',
        releaseChannel: 'PROD',
    },
  WebBrowser: {
    openBrowserAsync: jest.fn()
    }
  },
 }));

it('click on terms and conditions link', () => {
   const mock = jest.spyOn(WebBrowser, 'openBrowserAsync'); 
   mock.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
   // above statement return 'Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given' 
   // WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync = jest.fn(); --> This returns `WebBroser undefined
   const wrapper = shallow(<AboutScreen />);
   wrapper.find({ testId: 't-and-c' }).simulate('click');
   expect(mock).lastCalledWith('abc');
   // expect(WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync).toHaveBeenCalledWith('tcUrl);
});
```

I was able to mock the `Constants.manifest.version` but unable to figure out how to mock the function within the 'Browser` object.

Answer (score 2):

You're close.

---

You are currently mocking `WebBrowser` to be a property *inside* of `Constants`, so that needs to be moved out like this:

```js
jest.mock('expo', () => ({
  Constants: {
    manifest: {
      version: '0.0.1',
      releaseChannel: 'PROD',
    }
  },
  WebBrowser: {
    openBrowserAsync: jest.fn()
  }
}));
```

---

The other issue is how `simulate` works when using `shallow`.  From the [Common Gotchas](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html#common-gotchas) section of the doc:

> Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event, `.simulate()` will in fact target the component's prop based on the event you give it. For example, `.simulate('click')` will actually get the `onClick` prop and call it.

...and since your component doesn't have an `onClick` property calling `.simulate('click')` ends up doing nothing.

[This post](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/991#issuecomment-313203726) from an Airbnb dev recommends invoking props directly and avoiding `simulate`.

You can invoke `onPress` by calling the prop directly like this:

```js
wrapper.find({ testId: 't-and-c' }).props().onPress();
```

---

So all together the working test looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import config from '../../config';
import AboutScreen from '../AboutScreen';
import { Constants, WebBrowser } from 'expo';
const { termsAndConditionsUrl, privacyPolicyUrl } = config;

jest.mock('expo', () => ({
  Constants: {
    manifest: {
      version: '0.0.1',
      releaseChannel: 'PROD',
    }
  },
  WebBrowser: {
    openBrowserAsync: jest.fn()
  }
}));

it('click on terms and conditions link', () => {
  const mock = jest.spyOn(WebBrowser, 'openBrowserAsync');
  mock.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());

  const wrapper = shallow(<AboutScreen />);

  wrapper.find({ testId: 't-and-c' }).props().onPress();
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('tcUrl'); // Success!
});
```

Comment: how to restore `Constants` mock ?

Comment: this worked, but how do you wait for the promise resolution after firing the event?